# Can't compile with Metro Library on Arduino IDE (1.8.2)"multiple definition of --------"

Tags: arduino, microsoft-metro, multiple-definition-error

I'm struggling to compile my code with the Metro Library on Arduino IDE (1.8.2). The error message is below. Please help.

> /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/libraries/Metro/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Metro::Metro()':
>   (.text+0x0): multiple definition of`Metro::Metro()'
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/sketch/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/libraries/Metro/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Metro::Metro()':
>   (.text+0x0): multiple definition of`Metro::Metro()'
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/sketch/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/libraries/Metro/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Metro::Metro()':
>   (.text+0x0): multiple definition of`Metro::Metro(unsigned long)'
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/sketch/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/libraries/Metro/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Metro::Metro()':
>   (.text+0x0): multiple definition of`Metro::Metro(unsigned long)'
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/sketch/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/libraries/Metro/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Metro::Metro()':
>   (.text+0x0): multiple definition of`Metro::interval(unsigned long)'
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/sketch/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/libraries/Metro/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Metro::Metro()':
>   (.text+0x0): multiple definition of`Metro::check()'
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/sketch/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/libraries/Metro/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Metro::Metro()':
>   (.text+0x0): multiple definition of`Metro::reset()'
>   /var/folders/5v/b9y8xywj57n8wvns5hqqsprw0000gn/T/arduino_build_836199/sketch/Metro.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two copies of library in different places, where compiler is looking for code.

First copy of library is in the folder:

```
var/folders/.../arduino_build_836199/sketch/
```

Second copy is in the folder:

```
var/folders/.../arduino_build_836199/libraries/Metro/
```

Remove one of this (I think, from `/sketch/` folder, but it's up to you, depending of what are you trying to do).